# How to run many screen commands easily?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I need to open 20 windows and run `screen`. I have to run `screen` like below one by one. Is there a script way to run `screen`?

```
screen -S window1;do something; control a+d
.................
screen -S window19;do something; control a+d
screen -S window20;do something; control a+d
```

Comment: What about `at`? You can make different commands run at the same time. Or maybe use `cron`?

Comment: You might be able to use the `-X` option to send a command to an existing session, rather than attaching to it. There's also `-d -m` for starting a session without attaching to it.